# Cursor position doesn't end up at correct position after label

Tags: html, css

When I type something after label then it concat in label's text
The basic code is:

```
<p contenteditable="true">Hello, can I speak to <b><label>name</label></b>please?</p>
```

```css
label
{
     border: 1px solid black;
    float: none;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Hello, can I speak to <b><label>name</label></b>please?</p>
```

What I need is when I type something out of the box of label then shouldn't bind with label's text it should be before `please?` text..there is something wrong with css.. I couldn't find out..Thanks

Comment: welcome to the cruel and unusual world of `contenteditable`

Comment: @scniro :D why so?

Comment: If you're doing something simple, perhaps not as much. However, if this a launch point for some extensive work - I'd urge you to look at frameworks such as [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) or other rich text abstractions that have taken the beating upfront. Browsers _might_ be better these days, but `contenteditable` was notorious for having what I called phantom issues with apparently no solution, kind of like this one. Maddening. It's more apparent if your browser support needs to be broad as well.

Comment: Well said @scniro `contenteditable` is like the sea, a cruell mistress.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**

> *"If user can delete space then what?"*

My counter reply is:

> What exactly is the purpose of this code?

Anyway, this is the final edit take it or leave it.

> **Wrap each segment in a `<span contenteditable=true>...</span>` and separate them with a `&nbsp;`. If we want no space between the `<span>`s then we can use `&#65279;` (*zero width* no-break space) instead of `&nbsp;` Also note that the `<label>` and `<p>` tags wrap the `<span>`s. This preserves the HTML structure. See updated Snippet.**

Seeing that OP requires HTML/CSS solution -- and never mentions JavaScript/jQuery -- this is the best solution I can think of. Anymore behavior needed would be beyond HTML/CSS capabilities and JavaScript/jQuery would be needed. Having said that, I believe this solution will work. It's now impossible for the `<label>` to bleed into the text outside of it's borders because the `&nbsp;` is not editable now, yet each separate `<span>` is editable. When parsed, the only change in appearance is the blue outline. That shouldn't be a problem given the fact that OP has bold text with a border in the middle of a sentence.

**EDIT**

OP requires that everything is editable within the `<p>`. OP's concern was the `<label>`'s edits bleeding into the text. A `&nbsp;` placed after the `<label>` seems to fix that behavior.

---

Add `contenteditable="true"` to the `<label>` instead of the`<p>`

**SNIPPET**

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: none;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p><span contenteditable="true">Hello, can I speak to</span>&nbsp;<label><span contenteditable="true"><b>name</b></span></label>&nbsp;<span contenteditable="true">please?</span></p>

<p><span contenteditable="true">Hello, can I speak to</span>&#65279;<label><span contenteditable="true"><b>name</b></span></label>&#65279;<span contenteditable="true">please?</span></p>
```

Comment: Before the label? Oh I see, just a minute BRB

Comment: this structure is fix..P tag is editable.. I can't change

Comment: @Dhara I placed a `&nbsp; between `<label>` and `</b>` try it now.

Comment: @Dhara Ok placed the CEdit atrib back to original spot. The placement of the `&nbsp;` still in question...does it resolve your problem?

Comment: I think Its not a valid solution..If user can delete space then what?

Comment: @Dhara See final solution. There's no way to break it now.

Comment: as I said this structure is fixed.. I can't modify it.. I have to change only css or if necessary then can apply jquery.. can't add more tag in it

Comment: Then you'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery I'm afraid. I deal with dynamic structure and content that I have no control over on a daily basis. The most effective way to fix it was to learn JavaScript/jQuery because HTML/CSS is too limited. You can add the proper tags on this question or create a new question and reference this one.